# MVC ModelState.IsValid Ajax Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax function that is automatically fired when I submit a contact form, however I need to prevent the function from firing unless the form passes the model validation.

**Wedding.cs**

```
public class Wedding
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1,}$", ErrorMessage = "Name length must be greater than or equal 1 characters and contain letters only.")]

    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$",ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, Wedding model)
{
    var name = formCollection["Name"];
    var email = formCollection["EmailAddress"];
    var guestNumber = formCollection["GuestNumber"];
    var events = formCollection["Events"];

    var message = formCollection["Message"];

    ViewBag.Name = name;
    ViewBag.EmailAddress = email;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            _cf.SendEmail("RSVP from " + name, email, "something@ourdomain.com", "This is an email confirmation that " + name + " and " + guestNumber + " guest(s) will be attending " + events + " event(s).", "something@ourdomain.com", true, null, ";");
        }
        else
        {
            _cf.SendEmail("Contact from " + name, email, "something@ourdomain.com", message, "something@ourdomain.com", true, null, ";");
        }
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "rsvp_form", role = "form"}))
{
    <div class="rsvp-name">
        <div class="rsvp-formwrap">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.Name, placeholder = "Name", required = "required"})
            <div class="input-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsvp-formwrap">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.EmailAddress, placeholder = "Email Address", type = "Email", required = "required" })
            <div class="input-border"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsvp-guest">
        <label for="GuestNumber" class="lable-guest">Guests</label>
        <div class="rsvp-guestform">
            <div class="guestform">
                <select name="GuestNumber" class="select" id="GuestNumber">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsvp-event">
        <div class="rsvp-formwrap">
            <div class="rsvp-eventform">
                <div class="eventform">
                    <select name="Events" class="select" id="event">
                        <option value="All">All Events</option>
                        <option value="Wedding Party">Wedding Party</option>
                        <option value="Wedding Ceremony">Wedding Ceremony</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-border"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_rsvp"/>
    <button type="submit" name="rsvp_submit" class="rsvp-button">I Am Attending</button>
}

$(function(){
    $('#rsvp_form').ajaxForm(function(){
        $('#rsvp_form').slideUp();
        $('.title-rsvp-form').fadeOut( 'slow', function(){
            $(this).fadeIn().html( 'Thank You <br/> Your RSVP has been sent' );
            $(this).animate({
                'margin-top' : '170px'
            });
        });
    });
});


/*-------------------------------------------*/
/*  RSVP AJAX Form Function */
/*-------------------------------------------*/
$(function() {
    // Binding a click event
    // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
    $('#contact-button').bind('click', function(e) {
        // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
        e.preventDefault();
        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
       $('.element').bPopup({
            speed: 650,
            fadeSpeed: 'slow',
            transition: 'slideDown'
        });
    });

});
```

I have typical required placeholder elements on the form, but I need to ensure that the regular expressions are followed and at present the form will not submit if data is not entered in the respective fields, but if there is data entered the form is submitted, the Ajax function is fired but then the model state is checked and when the view is reloaded with the model validation errors the Ajax function blocks out the form so the user cannot see what needs to be corrected.

Any help would me much appreciated :-)

Comment: If you are making an Ajax call then maybe you should return a Json object that has a boolean if the Model is successful and then in your Javascript code you can write: if (success){ //Go to different page}

Comment: Am I on the right track with return `if (!ModelState.IsValid){return BadRequest(ModelState);}`?

Comment: Well in order to do client side validation you can use @Html.ValidationMessage(m => m.Property) and then enable client side validation. On the server end you can write: if (!ModelState.IsValid){ return Json(success = false);}else { ... return Json(success = true, url = ...);}

Comment: If I return 'Json(success = false)' how do I pass that value to the Ajax function, apologies but I'm not great with jQuery or Ajax.

Comment: If you have your Ajax call like this: $.ajax({ url : 'some url', data: $(form).serialize(); success: function(data){ if (data.success){//Do Code}}});

Comment: I have included the Ajax code in the section `Index.cshtml` but unfortunately I don't have any code that is similar to your function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68765/discussion-between-tabz100-and-iggyweb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all of the above code I needed the following scripts adding to my project:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Now the form prevents any submission where the ModelState is invalid and my successful message only appears if the ModelState is valid.

Comment: My form is inside bootstrap modal and the above solution is not working for me.